Is Schrodinger's cat a problem of how we define identity?
I apologize if the question is somehow silly or useless. I was reading about the infamous Schrödinger's cat paradox and I thought that if we consider that a cat is composed of numerous atomic particles, defining simple particles in superposition presents no issue. A "cat" is a human construct to represent a grouping of atoms or subatomic particles interacting with each other, and notions of life or death emerge from atomic behavior. For instance, a single-celled bacterium is alive, but if you separate the macromolecules that combined to create the bacterium, these units are not alive. Since life is an emergent property, there should be no contradiction in the cat being alive or not. Everything, including ourselves, is quantum. Consider a house made of bricks—when organized, it's a house, but they remain bricks. This underscores that observers, cats, and what we perceive as "classical" are emergent properties of an underlying quantum and elementary world. We label a certain group of atoms as living, as in the case of a live cat. If we consider everything as quantum, paradoxes like Schrodinger’s cat and Wigner's friend may dissolve, right?

Heresy as it may be, I just consider Schrodinger's Cat as a badly thought out thought experiment, and that what it shows is that even a genius can make mistakes.

This Veritasium video explains Schrodinger's cat on the way to something else. - Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why

Schroedinger's point is that ordinary macroscopic systems have definite macroscopic state, thus quantum-theoretic description allowing superposition of macroscopic states is inadequate for them. General problems with definition of life are immaterial to his argument, and ideas about emergence do not contradict his point.

Early versions of quantum theory (called the "Copenhagen Interpretation") contained a (subjectively) weird thing called the "Heisenberg cut" the idea of the Heisenberg cut is (roughly) that very small things follow the rules of quantum mechanics, but there is a "cut" in size, and sufficiently large things (like people, or experimental apparatus) don't.
This looks like it sort-of works, it lets you use quantum rules for small things, and allows big things to behave as we expect them to. The Schrödinger's cat thought experiment basically ruined this idea, because it forces you to put the "cut" at a size bigger than the size of a cat (and obvious generalisations of the argument make it as big as you like).
That leaves you with the problem of understanding how we end up with a reality that looks classical on our scale, but is made-up of lots of little quantum things. These days I think lots of people favour decoherence as an approach, but there are many others.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The idea that the property of being alive is emergent doesn't mean it is an illusion. There is a real objective difference between a cat being alive and a cat being dead. A living cat breathes in oxygen and exhales gases with a larger concentration of carbon dioxide. A living cat may hunt and kill birds and then the killed birds similarly don't move around or exhale carbon dioxide. More generally the idea that an emergent phenomenon isn't real means that almost all of science is about things that aren't real. Indeed, since particles are an emergent feature of quantum fields in certain regimes that means all particles are illusions. It also means there is no objective difference between people coming up with true theories by experimental science and false ones by reading entrails. See "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch Chapter 1 for more on this issue.
On Schrodinger's cat specifically, the issue is that a cat ends up in a superposition of being alive and dead and we don't see such superpositions. In quantum physics without collapse modifications to its equations of motion, when information is copied out of a system that supresses interference: this is called decoherence. A cat and a person are both large systems that interact with the environment on timescales a lot shorter than those on which they evolve and so they are decoherent systems:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
As a result, on macroscopic scales of space and time reality looks approximately like a collection of non-interacting parallel universes and we don't see multiple versions of the cat:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
These parallel universes themselves are emergent they are relatively large scale flows of information: on a suitably small scale, the world isn't divided into parallel universes, e.g. - electrons in your atoms are interfering a lot as they have to be to explain the existence of atoms.
